# fixed element in responsive layout

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element in my site which position i change from relative to fixed on scroll by following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(window).scroll(function(){if($(this).scrollTop() > 200 ){
    if($('#order_link').css("position") == "relative"){
      $('#order_link').css({"position":"fixed", "right": "290px", "top": "-20px"});
    }
  }else{
     $('#order_link').css({"position":"relative", "right": "0", "top": "0px"});
  }
});
```

But when I reduce the window `width`  `#order_link` got to far from the border of the site 
[image]

How can I fix the it ? this is my site http://sprint.tmweb.ru/my-dealem/pechat/businesscard.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution. change the `css` as below:

```
.art-nostyle{
     position:relative;
}
.art-nostyle .custom{
     height: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     width: 220px;
 }
.art-nostyle .custom #order_link{
     position:initial;
 }
```

And change the `jquery` as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){if($(this).scrollTop() > 200 ){
       if($('#order_link').css("position") == "relative"){
           $('#order_link').css({"position":"fixed", "right": "initial", "top": "-20px"});
       }
    }else{
        $('#order_link').css({"position":"relative", "right": "initial", "top": "0px"});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is use `%` value instead of `px`.

```
$('#order_link').css({"position":"fixed", "right": "10%", "top": "-20px"});
```

Or you can use media query to set your right value when screen size is small. And you can check window size in JQuery also to reduce/ change right value.

Answer (score 0):

Put the red heading inside a `position: relative` `div`, then make that button `position: absolute` from `right: 0px` inside said `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a percent value not pixel in this case. Using a percent value will position the #order_link relative to the width of window as oppose to pixel. So, replace this;

```
$('#order_link').css({"position":"fixed", "right": "290px", "top": "-20px"});
```

with this;

```
$('#order_link').css({"position":"fixed", "right": "5%", "top": "-20px"});
```

Notice the value of the `right` property has been replaced with `percent (5%)` rather than `pixel (290px)`. Of course, you can specify a different percent value if you want.

Comment: is that mean that i need to specify the window `width` via the jQuery, because it does not work only with one value I need to put something like `@media` by jQuery